# GNUradio open exception

Tags: python, linux

I use gnuradio do some research. when I type "sudo gnuradio-companion" in Linux terminal.There are some exception occurs. I can't open gnuradio and use it's GUI.
Who has encountered such a situation before ? who can tell me how to fix it ?
thanks a lot !!

the information on the terminal when execute "sudo gnuradio-companion"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is surprisingly simple:

You should **never** use `sudo` for anything that isn't for system administration.

Don't run `sudo gnuradio-companion` under **any** circumstances. It allows arbitrary execution of code (that's what it's designed to do, it's a software design tool), and hence **must not** be run as root.

I don't know where you got the idea to run `gnuradio-companion` with `sudo` – but you should probably not trust the source where you got that from.

Comment: Thank you all the same.
type sudo gnuradio-companion and gnuradio-companion to execute, the result are same. Don't run sudo gnuradio-companion can't solve this problem.